# Where can I find a list of all experimental_option 'prefs' keys for Edge as 'download.default_directory' and 'download.prompt_for_download'?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm using Python with Selenium to automate Edge.

Where can I find a list of all experimental_option 'prefs' keys for Edge as 'download.default_directory' and 'download.prompt_for_download'?

In other words, the keys of the dictionary for 'prefs' you can read about on page *[Capabilities and EdgeOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options)*.

I've tried to search at my best on the web.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find them in chromium source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/4aaa9f29d8fe5eac55b8632fa8fcb05a68d9005b/chrome/common/pref_names.cc.

For example, you can find `download.default_directory` and `download.prompt_for_download` in the file:

```
// String which specifies where to download files to by default.
const char kDownloadDefaultDirectory[] = "download.default_directory";

// Boolean which specifies whether we should ask the user if we should download
// a file (true) or just download it automatically.
const char kPromptForDownload[] = "download.prompt_for_download";
```